# Force the user to input value in cell based on another cells value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently working on the following excel workbook that is to be used for recording test cases:
[image]

If the user enters `fel` in the F column, it will color it red. `Fel` means `fault`" (in swedish) so I want to force the tester to register this error in the bug tracking system whenever one of the test-cases fails. The column I should contain which ID to this error in the bug tracking system. So what I'm trying to achieve is:

If the tester have entered `fel` in the column F, it should force or make the tester aware of that no ID have been entered in the I column. One idea is to color the corresponding I cell red if the F cell contains `fel` and the I cell is empty, and when the tester enters something in the I cell the red color goes away.

This is what I've done so far:

```
=IF(AND(F5="Fel",I5=ISEMPTY(TRUE)),)
```

which I use with conditional formatting but I'm unable to get it to work. Also the cell values are hard coded, how could i make the condition be valid for a certain column with a corresponding row's cell.

Also, I'm open to suggestions if there is a better way then to just color that cell red to make the user aware of that he needs to enter something in the I column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am taking the example of Cells `F1:F10`. Please amend as applicable.

There is no formula as `ISEMPTY`. Use `ISBLANK`

Use this formula

```
=AND($F1="Fel",ISBLANK($I1))
```

To ensure that it works for all cells in that range (`F1:F10`) use `$` for the column only thereby making it constant and the row a variable

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Got it to work now. Using `=AND($F5="Fel",ISBLANK($I5))` and saying that it should be valid for `=$I$5:$I$1000`. Thank you!